# Magento error on upgradation

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, upgrade, magento-1.9

I just upgraded my magento site to the latest version. Now I get `There has been an error processing your request.`

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1332131096507

Here is the content of the log:

> a:5:{i:0;s:190:"Error in file: "/home/********/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/sql/log_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.6.1.0-1.6.1.1.php" - SQLSTATE[70100]: <>: 1317 Query execution was interrupted";i:1;s:986:"
>
> /home/********/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
>
> /home/********/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.1.0', '1.6.1.1')
>
> /home/********/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.1.0', '1.6.1.1')
>
> /home/********/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
>
> /home/********/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
>
> /home/********/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>
> /home/********/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> /home/********/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Resolved it after upgrading the version and clearing the files at var/cache.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
This helped me:

- Truncate the table `log_visitor_info`, my had 500 MB (over 4.000.000 entries, timeout by magento when update this table)
- Open Website to update database again by magento automatically
- on some servers do this:

Firstly, copy `/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` to `/app/code/local/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`.

Then on line 91 or near this line, you will find:
`'cache_dir' => null,`
Change to:
`'cache_dir' => "var/tmp/",`